# How to get temporary filename so I can add it as mail attachment?

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I'm generating a file as below:

```
require_once("class/BuildFile.php");

$myfile = BuildFile::createFile($arg1, $arg2);
```

What's the best way to get the temporary filename of $myfile?
What do I need to add in 'createFile' to return the filename and path?

I want to add the file as an attachment using PHPMailer

```
$mail->AddAttachment(filename & path of $myfile);
```

I'm not sure whether I should be using tempnam or getPath() or something else ..

Thanks if you can help ..

Comment: with out seeing the method "createFile" its impossible to know

Comment: createFile is a long method that returns a file. If I do a var_dump($myfile) it shows that the filename is "/tmp/51a5d3795c59e/51a5d3795c59e.file" .. I'd like to know what this path and filename is each time I call createFile

Comment: well that is the path and file name.

Comment: Yes - but it will be different each time I call the method .. I need to get this path & filename so I can include it in $mail->AddAttachment(..)

Comment: of course, the file name is random

Comment: yes - so this is what I'm trying to figure out .. What code do I need to add to createFile or otherwise so I know the random filename of my temporary file such that I can add it as a mail attachment ?

Comment: phpmailer has `->AddStringAttachment()`, which allows you create a file attachment using a string as a source, rather than an actual on-disk file.

Comment: If I use $mail->AddStringAttachment(); what should I put as the argument so it adds the correct file?